# How to create a timer in an html table by using timestamp from django model?

Tags: javascript, django, datetime

I am trying to create a vehicle dashboard in django which lets user enter the vehicle details. When the model is saved the Checkintime is saved by auto_now_add = true. Now  I also want to create a timer which tells how much time elapsed from the time the vehicle was checked in.

I have tried parsing the date time to a javascript variable and then create a timer but without any luck. it either gives me a invalid date or doesn't return anything.

```
   # Create your models here.
  class Checkin(models.Model):
         vehicle_num = models.CharField(max_length = 13, blank = True, null = True)
         Driver_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True)

         AIPL1 = 'AIPL-1'
         AIPL2 = 'AIPL-2'
         AIPL6= 'AIPL-6'
         AIPL7 = 'SAMUDRA'
         OUTSOURCE = 'OUTSOURCE'

         BU_CHOICES=(
                    (A1,'A1'),
                    (A2,'A2'),
                    (A6,'A6'),
                    (A7,'A7'),
                    (OS,'OS'),
                    )

                    BusinessUnit = models.CharField(
                     max_length = 20,
                     choices = BU_CHOICES,
                     default = 'AIPL1'
                     )

         Loading = 'Loading'
         Unloading = 'Unloading'
         Type_Choices = (
                         (Loading,'Loading'),
                         (Unloading,'Unloading'),
                        )
         Type = models.CharField(
                        max_length = 20,
                        choices = Type_Choices,
                        default = 'Loading'
                        )
CheckinTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

## this is the view

```
def listView(request):
   vehicle_list_load = list(Checkin.objects.all().filter(Type ='Loading'))
   vehicle_list_unload = list(Checkin.objects.all().filter(Type 
   ='Unloading'))
   current_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
   # current_time = datetime.datetime.now() # tried All these
   # mdl = Checkin.objects.get(pk =1)
   # date_checked = getattr(mdl, CheckinTime)
   # diff = current_time - date_checked
   dt = current_time.date()
  diff = current_time
  return render(request,'vehicle_movement/listView.html', 
  {'vehicle_list_load':vehicle_list_load,
  'vehicle_list_unload':vehicle_list_unload,'diff':diff})
```

## This is the html

```
<table class = " table table-bordered table-hover">
        <th>Vehicle Number</th>
        <th>Driver's Name</th>
        <th>BusinessUnit</th>
        <th>Check in Time</th>
        <th>Action</th>

      {% for vehicles in vehicle_list_unload %}

      <tr>
        <td>{{vehicles.vehicle_num}}</td>
        <td>{{vehicles.Driver_name}}</td>
        <td>{{vehicles.BusinessUnit}}</td>
        <td>{{vehicles.CheckinTime}}</td>
        <!-- <td>{{vehicles.Type}}</td> -->
        <td>
          <script type="text/javascript" id = "demo">
            var checkin_time = new Date("{{ CheckinTime.isoformat }}")
            var now = new Date("{{current_time.isoformat}}")
            var distance  = checkin_time - now
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "
          </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
</table>
```

The above code is returning nothing at the moment. Can you please tell how can i calculate the difference between current time and the Checktime and display it in the html.Naive datetime is okayif it just gives timer

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? The view/template/JS

Comment: @IainShelvington - i tried a lot of combinations this is one of them.i don't have everything that i have tried at the moment.